# Naming convention for unique constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, naming-conventions, unique-constraint

Naming conventions are important, and primary key and foreign key have commonly used and obvious conventions (`PK_Table` and `FK_Table_ReferencedTable`, respectively).  The `IX_Table_Column` naming for indexes is also fairly standard.

What about the UNIQUE constraint?  Is there a commonly accepted naming convention for this constraint?  I've seen `UK_TableName_Column`, `UQ_TableName_Column`, and someone recommending `AX_TableName_Column` - I don't know where that comes from.

I've typically used `UQ` but I don't particularly like it, and I do not enjoy having to defend my choice of using it against a `UK` advocate.

I would simply like to see if there is a consensus on the most prevalent naming, or a good reasoning as to why one makes more sense than the others.

Comment: @Mitch Any reason why?  I do too but I always ask myself why noone just uses `U`.  What's the `Q` stand for?

Comment: You could ask the same question about IX for IndeX ... why not just I?

Comment: "UQ" is just an abbreviation of "UNIQUE". The reason for two letters is basically it's a set precedent by "PK".

Comment: Personally I ended up using UX_* for "Unique indeX", in homage to the default of IX for "IndeX". I particularly dislike UK_ because I'm from the United Kingdom. I could be persuaded on AK if that's what the internet likes.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst I have never seen such a convention but because of the upvotes it must be common and serve the purpose well. But having a foreign key named FK_03 is not very helpful, wouldn't it be better to name it `FK_TargetTable_SourceTable`? Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

My thinking is it isn't a key: it's a constraint.

It *could* be used as a key of course, and uniquely identifies a row, but it *isn't* the key.

An example would be that the key is "ThingID", a surrogate *key* used in place of ThingName the natural key. You still need to *constrain* ThingName: it won't be used as a key though.

I'd also use UQ and UQC (if clustered).

You could use a unique index instead and go for "IXU". By the logic employed, an index is also a key but only when unique. Otherwise it's an index. So then we'd start with `IK_columnname` for unique indexes and `IX_columnname` for non-unique indexes. Marvellous.

And the only difference between a unique constraint and a unique index is INCLUDE columns.

Edit: Feb 2013. Since SQL Server 2008, indexes can have filters too. Constraints can not

So, it comes down to one of

- stick with UQ as per the rest of the SQL-using planet
- use IK for unique indexes (IKC for clustered too) to be consistent...

Comment: Would you strongly prefer "IXU" over "UIX"?

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dtjones/2009/10/29/best-practice-naming-constraints/

Answer (score 195):

My naming convention for indices and constraints:

| Index/Constraint Type | Naming Convention |
| --- | --- |
| Primary key | ***<table-name>***`_PK` |
| Unique index/constraint | ***<table-name>***`_AK{xx}` |
| Non-Unique index | ***<table-name>***`_IX{xx}` |
| Check constraint | ***<table-name>***`_CK{xx}` |
| Default constraint | ***<table-name>***`_DF{xx}` |
| Foreign key constraint | ***<table-name>***`_FK{xx}` |

Where `{xx}` is a 2-digit sequence number, starting at 01 for each constraint type per table. Primary key doesn't get a sequence number since there can be only one. The 2-char alpha suffix meanings are:

| Suffix | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `PK` | **P**rimary **K**ey |
| `AK` | **A**lternate **K**ey |
| `FK` | **F**oreign **K**ey |
| `IX` | **I**nde**X** |
| `CK` | **C**hec**K** |
| `DF` | **D**e**F**ault |

I generally want to group metadata/system catalog data by the controlling object rather than by object type.

Comment: AK: Alternate Key is what SQL Server Data tools 2012's design surface calls them too.

Comment: @AlexKeySmith: **Thank you** for explaining why Microsoft uses AK for this!!

Comment: No problem @T.J.Crowder :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, in the entity-relationship/database modelling world, it is an *alternate* key, because, like the primary key, the column set comprising the alternate key must be unique, thus providing [alternate] identity for the row/tuple.

Comment: @NicholasCarey: No, I got it -- as soon as I saw Alex's comment, the light went on. :-)

Comment: I'm late to the party, but I always make a difference between "unique indexes" and unique constraints" those are two different things. They can show up simultaneously.

Comment: @TheImpaler: In SQL Server (topic at hand), a unique constraint creates a unique index. That's how SQL Server enforces the constraint.

Comment: @NicholasCarey I guess that's pretty much everywhere. However, you can have different case where you create a unique index, without creating a unique constraint.

Comment: Yes, but the fact that it is unique makes it a *key*: a key being a set of attributes for the table such that the table is unique for that set of attributes: that is, no two rows in the table have the same values for that set of attributes. However, strictly speaking, and if you want to be pedantic, such a set of attributes is not a key if it itself contains a proper subset of attributes, that likewise defines uniqueness (e.g., the set of attributes that make up the key can't contain extraneous attributes that don't contribute to the uniqueness.)

Comment: I think you missed `UX` for Unique index

Comment: @EugenKonkov — No. A unique index is an alternate key. A set of columns that makes the table/entity unique is, by definition, either the primary key or an alternate key.

Answer (score 11):

I use UQ. The K in UK makes me think of K as it's used in PK and FK. Well, after I think of United Kingdom anyways; ironic that this should be a prefix for UNIQUE when UK brings up so many other associations =)